# Android IMAP Client unrelated Attachment Size

Tags: android, exchange-server, imap

If attachment is more than 10 MB, in mail client displaying more size(13.4 MB) than actual attachment size(10MB). I observed this issue even in Default Google mail client in (S3)device.

I am modifying k-9 mail client. This issue observed even in default k9 mail app also. Please let me know what may be cause for this behavior .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are BASE64 encoded, so they actually take up more space than you think.  If you look at any binary file, for example, a JPG, the attached size is a lot bigger than the file would be on disk. The larger size is actually quite accurate, that's the actual number of bytes that the attachment takes up while in attachment form.

Once downloaded, the attachment will of course no longer be in BASE64 (or similar) format, and will once again be the exact size it is supposed to be.

From what I can tell looking at email formats, there's no easy way to retrieve the size of the attachment without decoding the BASE64 string first.

Comment: But how it is same in other email client like Windows and ios?

Comment: They compute the size using the attachment, for example, if you look at clients like Outlook, they download and cache the entire attachment, so it's easy to get the actual size.

Comment: RFC 3516 provides an easy way to get the exact size, BINARY.SIZE. For servers that don't support 3516, fetching BODY.SIZE[x] and multiplying by 0.75 provides an excellent estimate for base64-encoded attachments.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea about that ratio - thank you for sharing!  BINARY.SIZE isn't available a lot of the times, like you mentioned, but I love that ratio, that's sneaky!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an attachment can very easily be encoded in other encodings besides base64, like quoted-printable. Blindly applying any transformation based on a heuristic like "it's a big attachment, it must be bas64" would be completely wrong. There is also no reason to do so; simply look at the parsed `BODYSTRUCTURE` to see the content-transfer-encoding of each part.

With that out of my mouth, the base64 is actually a pretty handy encoding -- it will always encode a sequence of three octets into four bytes. However, MIME imposes additional constraints on the transmission (line length and such) and also adds some required headers. [The Wikipedia article on Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) has a nice formula to use: `bytes = (string_length(encoded_string) - 814) / 1.37`.